# How can I destructure react query async return variables so that one of them doesn't log undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

The Axios object doesn't have a `winnersData` property, so destructuring it returns `undefined` in the original block of ocde. I need to destructure data from both Axios requests and what I call them later on needs to be different.  I'm just not sure how to implement this and have been struggling for a while.  My attempt below fails as well.

How can I implement this?

Original block of code:

```
async function fetchUploads(){
        const headers = {
            "Accept": 'application/json',
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${authToken}`
        };

        const {data} = await axios.get('http://localhost/api/get-user-uploads-data', {headers});
        return data;
    }

async function fetchWinners(){
        const headers = {
            "Accept": 'application/json',
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${authToken}`
        };

        const {winnersData} =  axios.get('http://localhost/api/choose-winners', {headers});
        return winnersData
    }

    const { data }        = useQuery('uploads', fetchUploads)
    const { winnersData } = useQuery('winners', fetchWinners)
    console.log(data); // logs data correctly
    console.log(winnersData); // logs undefined

    return(....);
```

Attempted fix for `fetchWinners()` I've tried but it failed:

```
async function fetchWinners(){
    const headers = {
        "Accept": 'application/json',
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${authToken}`
    };

    const { winnersData } =  axios.get('http://localhost/api/choose-winners', {headers});
    return { winnersData };
}



const { data }        = useQuery('uploads', fetchUploads)
const { data: { winnersData } } = useQuery('winners', fetchWinners)
console.log(data.winnersData); // still logs undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like useQuery always returns a property called data, so you just need to rename it (same for the axios return). And don't forget an await for the axios call.

```
const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost/api/choose-winners', {headers});
return data;
...
const { data } = useQuery('uploads', fetchUploads);
const { data: winnersData } = useQuery('winners', fetchWinners);
console.log('winnersData', winnersData);
```

Comment: tried this but still getting undefined

Comment: You should check the typeof data. It may be contain nested object like data: {data: winnersData, status, statusText, response} and then you should de-structure the data variable according to received response type.